# Exposing a directory/location to the web

Tags: ubuntu, eggdrop

I have a VPS running Ubuntu and Apache

For example's sake, let's say the address is: `5.5.5.5`

- On the VPS I have a user named eggdrop (besides my root user).
- user eggdrop has a **home** directory path like so: `/home/eggdrop/`
- In that location I have a directory named `logs`, thus: `/home/eggdrop/logs/`
- The directory named `logs` contains two other directories named: `dir1` and `dir2`
- Thus: `/home/eggdrop/logs/dir1/` & `/home/eggdrop/logs/dir2/`

Those locations would contain various log files ***I'd like to make public*** for anyone who visits a specific link.

How then could I **expose** `dir1` to the following address, when typed in a browser: `5.5.5.5/dir1/` so that when someone visits that link, it would render a list of those log files contained in `/home/eggdrop/logs/dir1/`?

Linux ubuntu18 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Alias:

```
Alias /dir1 /home/eggdrop/logs/dir1/
<Directory /home/eggdrop/logs/dir1/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This line you can put into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf` , inside `VirtualHost` block.

Check your permission, if www-data user can read your logs directory.

Comment: Check /var/log/apache2/access.log and error.log .

Comment: other_vhosts_access.log says: `"GET /dir1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0` and so on..that's all. Nothing related in access.log or error.log

Comment: Might this be the problem? `By default, Ubuntu does not allow access through the web browser to any file apart of those located in /var/www, public_html directories (when enabled) and /usr/share (for web applications). If your site is using a web document root located elsewhere (such as in /srv) you may need to whitelist your document root directory in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

The default Ubuntu document root is /var/www/html. You can make your own virtual hosts under /var/www. This is different to previous releases which provides better security out of the box.`

Comment: Managed to get it working using your suggestion - thanks.